# Launching movie playback via "am start"

Tags: android, playback

I would like to launch a movie playback directly from the command line and the adb tools.

The way I do it, is with the instrumentation tool:

```
# am start -t video/mpeg -D /sdcard/Movies_3D/mymovie.mp4
```

But when I do that, 
com.cooliris.media/.MovieView take the intent, doesn't crash, but "is waiting for the debugger to attach"

How to specify directly the Media Player? I cannot find the class name to call.

(uninstalling com.coloris is not an option)

Thanks,

Comment: I am tring to add "-n com.android.media/.MediaPlayer", but doesn't change that much

Answer (score 7):

Following works on Android ICS (4.0.3) version

`am start -n  com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity -d <URI>`

For example, following command plays clip in /data/local/tests/ directory.

`am start -n  com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity -d file:////data//local//tests//big_buck_bunny_1080p_H264_AAC_25fps_7200K_short.MP4`

Comment: On my Android 5.1 device, this command makes the phone reboot.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Android 9.0

```
 adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW  -t video/mp4 -d file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/Video1.mp4
```